# add the same thing to a table column by  sql command

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a table named `test`. in it. there are some columns as this:

```
001.jpg
  ...
999.jpg
```

now i want to use a sql command to add a url before them. as this `http://www.example.com/xxx/001.jpg`.....is there a way to get this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your field is called `url`, a simple `UPDATE` query will do:

```
UPDATE test SET url = CONCAT("http://", url);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is two way to accomplish this task. It depends up to you that what you want?

If you want to add a url in the database permanently then you have to use update query with no any where condition, Although if you want to only show your field with this added url you have to use select query.

Please find below the examples for both:

Suppose that your table column name is `imageName` then `UPDATE` query will be

```
UPDATE test SET imageName = CONCAT("http://www.example.com/xxx/", imageName);
```

And the `SELECT` query will be

```
SELECT CONCAT("http://www.example.com/xxx/", imageName) FROM test;
```

Comment: Yeah, I should probably have questioned the OP's motives a bit more thoroughly. Modifying the string only at read-time is in all likelihood the more appropriate action.